# Could you explain whether following sentence is correct or not? Why?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> Under what conditions is it efficient for government to require us to obtain a permission to do something?

There are three questions I don't understand in this sentence: 
1. Can I put a preposition in front of "what" in special questions?
2. Is this structure correct? If not, what can we do to correct it?

3. If it is correct, will it be a formal usage or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove "a" before permission. It's an uncountable noun.  The rest is fine.

Comment: I suspect ***efficient*** in the example text doesn't reflect what OP is trying to say. To be efficient means to be "quick and easy" (involving minimum wasted effort or expense) - but it's hard to see how being required to obtain government permission could make something easier than just going ahead and doing it without wading through bureaucratic "red tape". A more suitable adjective might be ***effective*** - from the government's point of view, they can obviously manage things more effectively (so they ***work properly***) if they monitor and control everything people do.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Yes, the *preposition + question world" structure is common:

> **In which** of his plays does William Shakespeare tell the story of a young prince of Denmark who feigns madness to determine his father's murderer?  Is it "Hamlet"?
>
> Marketing decisions fall **under whose** authority at that company?  Let me know and I'll send them an introductory email.

However I suspect that, grammatically, these structures are considered more or less the same as single question words like *who, what, where* etc.  These have a more targeted application, since they can only be used in the appropriate context, but otherwise seem to act as the same part of speech.

2)  The only mistake is "a permission".  The natural phrase is "obtain permission" (or just "get permission") without any article.

> Yes, you can go play at your friend's house if you first **get permission** from your mother.

The other problem is the sentence is unnecessarily ambiguous.  Whose permission are "we" supposed to obtain?  If you mean *the government's* permission then say, "*their* permission."

3)  What you do mean by "formal"?  English has, at best, a loose hierarchy of *formality*, that varies considerably by region and context.

The only thing I can say is that "obtain permission" sounds more educated than "get permission".  If you have a specific idea about what would be "more formal" please let us know.

Comment: May I ask what "single question words" are?

Comment: @MingLai   Like *who, what where* and so on.  Both *"Who is your leader?"* and *"By whom are you led?"* are grammatical, and to me it seems both "who" and "by whom" act as the same part of speech.  Hopefully someone with more scholarship can add insight.